# React-Redux: State always one input behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've created a class based component that renders an input field. I need the global state to update *while* the user types into the input. The issue is that the global state is always one step (render?) behind from what's actually in the input field. For example, when I write “winners” in the input, the state is “winner” instead. How can I fix this?

#### Component

```js
class TeamCardT1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // local state
        this.state = {
            team_one_name: "Team One",
        };

        // bind events
        this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
    };

    handleName = e => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            team_one_name: e.target.value
        });
        this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);
    };


    render() {
        const { team_one_name } = this.state;

        return (
            <>
            <div className="teamCard_container">
                <input
                type="text"
                id="team_one_name"
                name="team_one_name"
                value={team_one_name}
                onChange={this.handleName}
                maxLength="35"
                minLength="2"
                className="teamCard_teamName" />
        
                <PlayersCardT1 />
                <ScoreCard />
            </div>
        </>
        )
    };
}
```

#### index.js for the component

```js
const mapStateToProps = ({ team_one_name }) => {
    return {
        team_one_name,
    };
};

// Dispatch 
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        handleSubmit: (data) => { dispatch(updateTeamOneName(data)) }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TeamCardT1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `handleSubmit` with the previous state, change to the current value.

```
handleName = e => {
        this.setState({ team_one_name: e.target.value });
        this.props.handleSubmit(e.target.value);
    };
```

Notice that you already have a shallow merge with `setState` so you don't need to destruct `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

state is one step behind because you should call the prop function as a setState callback by this way the prop function will call just after the state set.

```
handleName = e => { 
    this.setState({ 
        ...this.state,
        team_one_name: e.target.value
        }, () => {
        this.props.handleSubmit({value: e.target.value});
    }); 
};
```